# Executing a python script using IronPython [c#]

Tags: c#, python

I wrote this code in python to draw [dendrogram](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=dendrogram%20python&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWs8nI-YfaAhVOalAKHU3YCPMQ_AUICigB&biw=911&bih=467#imgrc=mIQfvmShBb_nJM:):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage,dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([[2,3],[5,5],[4.3,6],[5.5,4.9],[4.4,5.8],[10,10],[40,40], 
[2.2,5]])
plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],s=30)
lin=linkage(x,"single")
den=dendrogram(lin,truncate_mode="none")
plt.show()
```

It works correctly and generates the dendrogram. After that, I want to convert this code to a method in Python script and execute it over a `C#` project so I can use IronPython.

But there is an error in the script at this part `linkage(x,"single")`, truncate_mode = "none" and this line `plt.show()`, as shown in the following `c#` code:

```
  var pySrc =
  @"def Generatedendrogram():
  import numpy as np
  from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage,dendrogram
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  x = np.array([[2,3],[5,5],[4.3,6],[5.5,4.9],[4.4,5.8],[10,10],[40,40]])
  plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],s=30)

  //There is an error in the next 2 lines
  dendrogram(linkage(x,"single"), truncate_mode = "none")
  plt.show()";

  // host python and execute script
  var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
  var scope = engine.CreateScope();
  engine.Execute(pySrc, scope);

  // get function and dynamically invoke
  var dendro = scope.GetVariable("Generatedendrogram");
  Generatedendrogram();
```

How can I write this script correctly?

Comment: `numpy` isn't distributed as 100% python scripts. It has binaries for performance-critical parts. Unfortunately, inronpython isn't designed to run those binary part of a python module.

Comment: Do you suggest  any way to use such as those binary part of python module in c# code ?

Comment: How can i use this python code in c# ?